# How do I get the proper js file?

Tags: ydn-db

At some point, I somehow downloaded the file ydn.db-isw-sql-e-cur-qry-dev.js.  I don't recall exactly what options I chose on the download site to get this file, but it works perfectly.

I now want to get a non-dev version as well as the .map.  I tried following the instructions to build my own library, but I couldn't get it to work.

I also can't find the files I need here: https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db

Any tips on how I can get the files I need?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see the [setup page (Modules symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050719/how-do-i-get-the-proper-js-file) for what you have used for download, whereas isw stands for indexedDB, webSQL and webStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your file name, you need SQL, Cursor, Event and Query module for Indexedb-Websql-WebStorage mechanisms.

I don't think, compiled file for production. You need to register for paid support :-( Anyways dev version can be used in production too. Dev version will be a bit slower since it will check correctness in multuple checkpoints, and accordingly larger file size.